# Print only first of two strings in a LinkedList node?

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I have a `LinkedList` of pairs of names. Each node will have two strings. I need to print only the first name in each node.

The original list will be:

```
Sarah, Paul --> Paul, John --> Roger, Mike --> Mike, Jacob -->.
```

I need the output to be:

```
Sarah, Paul, Roger, Mike
```

I'm completely lost on how to do this, any help would be appreciated

Comment: What's so hard about this ? You just need to iterate over the list

Comment: @Dici, I don't even know what that is let alone how to do it

Answer (score 1):

You mean like

```
 for (Pair p: linkedList) {
      System.out.print(p.getFirst() + " ");
 }
```

Comment: This seems like a great way to go about it, but I've never use pairs before so I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: It just depends on what kind of "Pair" you have, it's just another class, and you need to use the getter that applies in your case. Check the API.

Comment: I made the Pair class and understand how it works (it's the same as any other object). However, I'm still not sure how to make a pair out of my list. If I try to make a new pair by doing Pair(list.get(i)) it's telling me that the list is only one string, even though each list node contains two separate strings. (I really appreciate your help, by the way).

Comment: @Rachel : Not meaning to be rude, but you seem to be trying things that you don't even understand. You should review the basics first.